# ¿Como enviar por parametro de tipo string que contiene caracteres especiales a la funcion del controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

En la vista tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
 $("#btn_descargar").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        debugger;
        var iBody = $("#iframeID").contents().find("body");
        var myContent = iBody.find("#myContent").text();      

        var url = '/Factura/DescargarXML?textoXML=' + myContent + '';
        window.location.href = url;
    });
```

En el controller:

```
 public ActionResult DescargarXML(String textoXML)
    {

        byte[] arr = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textoXML);
        var fileStreamResult = File(arr, "application/octet-stream", "DTE.xml");
        return fileStreamResult;
    }
```

Pero cuando la variable myContent(string que envio como parametro) contiene caracteres como '<' o '>' (sin comillas), no me funciona. En este caso quería enviar un string que contenía lo siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<EnvioDTE version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte EnvioDTE_v10.xsd">
<SetDTE ID="ID78450470-0__1__33__137175">
```

He tratado de convertir en binario (byte[]) en la vista con javascript, pero al hacerlo, queda separado por comas, lo cual es imposible que reciba parametros por comas en controller, ya que dice que no encuentra el recurso.

El objetivo del porque uso window.location.href, es para descargar documentos, en este caso un xml.

Si alguien tiene alguna idea de como enviar estos datos, se lo agradecería mucho

Comment: Hay dos opciones, la primera que utilices la acción POST en lugar de get, eso te ayudaría, la siguiente es usar URL Enconde, puedes ver más detalles aquí https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.urlencode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_HttpServerUtility_UrlEncode_System_String_

Comment: podrias dar algun ejemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes usar una codificacion que pueda pasar caracteres especiales como parte de la consulta en el url. **Base64** es recomendado para estos casos. En javascript puedes codificar y decodificar Base64 con **btoa()** y **atob()** respectivamente. En C#:

#### Codificar

```
public static string Base64Encode(string str) {
  var tb= System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
  return System.Convert.ToBase64String(tb);
}
```

#### Decodificar

```
public static string Base64Decode(string base64Data) {
  var b= System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);
  return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);
}
```

#### Tus funciones

```
...
 var myContent = btoa(iBody.find("#myContent").text());      

public ActionResult DescargarXML(String str)
{

    byte[] arr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Base64Decode(textoXML));
    var fileStreamResult = File(arr, "application/octet-stream", "DTE.xml");
    return fileStreamResult;
}
```

Comment: ahora se que el motivo del error dice que:
 El módulo Solicitar filtrado está configurado para denegar una solicitud cuando la cadena de consulta sea demasiado larga.

Comment: La razon es que los parametros pasados por GET no pueden ser muy largos, te recomiendo en este caso el metodo POST, alli puedes pasar un xml mucho mas grande.